How to stop listening for proximity in background with react-native-device-info
Our react native app is supposed to be used as audio guide in museums, that's why we implement a feature that encourages users to hold the device to their ear if no headphones are connected, so that the noise in the museum is reduced.
To do this, I use react-native-device-info to listen for proximity changes.
Proximity.addListener(proximityCallback);

On Android (not sure about iOS, not tested yet) this causes that the screen goes black if proximity is detected.
That's ok, while the app is running in foreground. But this happens even if the app is in background, what makes the usage of the phone (other apps) a bit difficult if the fingers get near the proximity sensor.
Is there a way to pause the listeners while the app is in background? Or do I have to do this manually, removing listeners when the app is in background and re-adding them when it is in foreground again?
